Using wired USB keyboard & mouse to control Fortnite on Switch
I have a wired USB keyboard & mouse hooked up my Switch. Without needing to do any configuration, the keyboard lights up indicating it's powered, and I can use it fine for eg text entry in Nintendo Shop.
However, when I load Fortnite, it doesn't respond to keyboard or mouse commands. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Do other games work? I could believe Fortnite on the Switch doesn't expect mouse and keyboard and just doesn't support them.

@Rup Various random Internet sources claim that Fortnite on Switch is one of the few games that does support keyboards.

Can you name one such source? I found a source claiming to have a list of "all" games supporting keyboard and mouse, which doesn't include Fortnite.

@Nolonar Here's one, although on closer inspection it looks like LLM spam: https://www.playbite.com/how-to-use-mouse-and-keyboard-on-nintendo-switch-fortnite/

Any chance you need to manually set your input device? If joycons are still connected as player 1 those might be the default option
